# How to use org-protocol and org-capture in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, org-capture

I've been having some problems when using `org` inside `spacemacs`. I make use of `org-protocol` to capture stuff that I find interesting when I'am browsing  and have it inside `spacemacs`. The problem is that I can't seem to get it this process to work flawlessly. Sometimes everything works fine but other times instead of opening the capture inside spacemacs I get `No server buffers remain to edit` and a new browser window pops up. Othertime I get `Error (use-package): org-projectile/:config: Symbol’s function definition is void: org-projectile:per-repo` and once again a new browser window pops up.

In my `.spacemacs` file I enabled the `org` layer and in `user-config` I have the following:

```
  (server-start)
  (use-package org-capture
    :bind ("<f8>" . org-capture)
    :after org)

  (use-package org-protocol 
    :after org)
```

Comment: Have you enabled `org-protocol` in `org-modules`? You can do this via `M-x customize-group RET org RET` or put the following in your init file: `(setq org-modules (quote (org-protocol)))`

Comment: @mclear I didn't but having done that it's now working normally. How did you know to do that? I didn't see any reference to `org-modules` in the documentation for `org-protocol` (to be honest I wasn't even aware that was a thing).

Comment: `org-protocol` is one of the ones listed in the module customize group. I then just looked at the code that was put in my `custom.el` file and went from there. There are some alternatives for listing modules described [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2010-04/msg00122.html). Should I put this as an answer to your question then?

Comment: Yes, go ahead. I feel this is something other people may end up having trouble with in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable `org-protocol` in `org-modules`. You can do this via `M-x customize-group RET org RET` or put the following in your init file: `(setq org-modules (quote (org-protocol)))`. There are also some other ways to enable modules as detailed [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2010-04/msg00122.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just inserting `org-protocol` into `org-modules` did not work for me, what helped was adding a `require`:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (require 'org-protocol)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't seem to have been the issue here, for reference I was also receiving the *No server buffers remain to edit* message.

Not 100% sure as I tried a number of things, but in my case it seemed to be because my capture template was pointing to a heading that didn't exist.